# Median points collinear: At least one outside triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose that ABC is a triangle and that $A'\in l_{BC}$, $B'\in l_{AC}$, and that $C'\in l_{AB}$. Prove that if $A', B', C'$ are collinear, then at least one of these points must be outside of the triangle.

I'm not sure how to prove that it is outside of the triangle.  I know that one way to prove if an element is outside of the triangle is to see if all of the cross products have the same sign for their third component, but I don't think that can help here.

Comment: What if $B'=C$ and $C'=B$?

Comment: I believe that being on the vertices constitutes that they are outside of the triangle if that is what you mean.

Comment: What is the definition of "outside the triangle"? If $A' = C$ and $B' = C' = A$, then none of the points would appear to be "outside the triangle."

Comment: If vertices are outside of the triangle I then suppose that also all the points on the sides of triangle $ABC$ are outside of the triangle. But then your theorem is trivially true, because $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$ are outside of the triangle by construction.

Answer (score 0):

It is a direct consequence of Menelaus' theorem  :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus'_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that uses pigeonhole principle:

Assume that $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$ are collinear.

- If *at least one* of three vertices of $\triangle ABC$ is on line $A'B'$, then at least one of two other points must be outside of line $A'B'$ (since $A$, $B$ and $C$ can't be collinear). Therefore, line $A'B'$ can't intersect the segment between these two points.
- If *none* of the vertices of $\triangle ABC$ is on the line $A'B'$, then, by pigeonhole principle, at least two of them must lie on the same half plane. Therefore, line $A'B'$ cannot intersect segment between these two points in the same half plane.

**Note:** Above proof assumes vertices counts as outside of the triangle as per OP's comment.